# cannot append to LinkedList implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list

I sketched up this small single linked list example. But for some reason, new node do not get appended to the list correctly.
Can someone help me by detecting the error please?

```
struct Node {
  Node(int x, Node *next = nullptr) : x{x}, next{next} {}
  int x;
  std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
};

class LinkedList {
public:
  LinkedList(std::vector<int> const &v) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < std::size(v); ++i) {
      auto temp = std::make_shared<Node>(v[i], nullptr);
      if (head == nullptr) {
        head = temp;
      } else {
        auto ptr = head;
        while (ptr != nullptr) {
          ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  std::shared_ptr<Node> head = nullptr;
};


int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
  auto l = LinkedList{v};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what `ptr` is when you assign it to `temp`.

It is a local variable that you initialized with the link list's `head` member before the while loop. When you assign `temp` to it, you know its value is the nullptr, okay. So you have assigned a pointer to a new node to a local variable that currently holds a nullptr. How is that going to add an item to your linked list?

To insert an item into the list you need a pointer to a node in the list and assign a pointer to its `next` member e.g.

```
...
auto ptr = head;
while (ptr->next != nullptr) {
   ptr = ptr->next;
}
ptr->next = temp;
...
```

But as mentioned in comments of this answer, the way you are inserting each item has O(n) running time as you need to iterate through the entire list to find the end. The correct way to do this would be for each insert to be O(1).

Comment: Side note: Since you just added the last node, you're in an excellent position to know exactly where it is and add the new node to it without having to find it again.

Comment: Rather than using `if (head == nullptr) { ... } else { ... }` on each loop iteration, it is customary (and more efficient) to use a `Node**` instead, eg: `auto** n = &head; for (...) { ... *n = temp; n = &((*n)->next); }` Of course, it is even more efficient to add a `tail` member to the list, then you can append new nodes even more efficiently.

Comment: thank you guys, is shared pointer the prefered pointer type here ?

Comment: There isn't really a "preferred pointer type" it depends on what you need. I mean, if you arent implementing a linked list for educational purposes the preferred thing would be to use std::list unless you have a good reason not to and also a good reason to not use std::vector.  Otherwise use shared_ptr if you actually need shared ownership; use unique_ptr if you don't. I do think using smart pointers in an educational exercise like this is commendable though.

Comment: thanks. it is for educational purposes actually. Otherwise I would rely on the STL ;)